# Crop Facebook and Instagram photos from page screenshots

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

So I have quite an interesting image segmentation problem. Here, I have scraped instagram photos which are stacked vertically.

see image here(too long to post): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASnvV.jpg

What I am trying to do is quite simple. I just want to extract each post image from the screenshot, and save it to some directory. I am trying to find ways to make this work, like cropping by pixel color at a certain height but none of it is working perfectly.

Any method that would quickly segment this image. Python BTW.

Comment: Some rather naive stuff like just trying to remove the background and then crop from there. I also tried stopping the crop everytime the pixel color changed at a certain height but those results also weren't stellar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with segmenting each post out. Use the gaps between each post (which are always uniform) to segment each post out.

Then approach capturing the image inside the post - breaking this down into 2 different problems will make your algorithm simpler in my opinion.

Comment: Any code? Not the easiest thing to segment iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas, not entirely sure how will they work for you, but thought they might give you some leads to try out:

1) All these instagram images seems to have a "heart" shaped icon just below the image you want to extract. Maybe figuring out detecting the heart shape might be good idea? Once you have found the "heart" you can look for the image just above it. Since it is a UI, my hope is that all the images that you want to extract will be a fixed number of pixels above the "heart". Moreover, they should also have the same height and width, I think.

2) Another possible idea is to find the edges in the image. Again, the images you want to extract seem to have a strong edge with respect to their background (but so does text and other UI elements). However, these edges should ideally have the largest area (which is also mostly fixed) enclosed between them. So, after finding the edges, you can use the find contours in function in opencv and then filter out the contours which have an area greater than a threshold. Have you tried something like this?